# Why is aqueous solution of lauyl glucoside alkaline?

Tags: organic-chemistry, aqueous-solution, ph, surfactants

What is the reaction of dissociation of lauryl glucoside? It's aqueous solution pH is much higher than 7, it's definately alkaline. Why is that? It's nonionic surfactant and as far as I know it only creates hydrogen bonds with water (the hydrophilic part of the molecule, oxygen atom). Lauryl glucoside is the combination of glucose and dodecanol. Glucose itself when diluted in water is neither acidic nor alkaline. Why is glucoside then alkaline?